# Windows container fails to build VS 2013 C++ project with error MSB6006: “midl.exe” exited with code -2147024774

Tags: c++, docker, msbuild, docker-for-windows, vcxproj

I should be able to build a C++ project on a windows docker container using MSBuild.exe

Command:

```
C:\'Program Files (x86)'\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe .\TestNative.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 /m /t:Build /p:ResGenExecuteAsTool=true /toolsversion:12.0
```

C++ Project fails to build with error:

```
Midl:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\midl.exe /W1 /nologo /char signed /env x64 /h “Enumglob.h” /tlb “x64\ReleaseMinDependency\TestNativeCore.tlb” Enumglob.idl
64 bit Processing .\Enumglob.idl
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1178,5): error MSB6006: “midl.exe” exited with code -2147024774.
```

....

....

Build FAILED.

Information

This is my Dockerfile which already has the Visual C++ Redistributables installed and the project copied over using *Docker cp* command. I’m not sure what else is missing and the error message is not helpful.

```
FROM chemsorly/msbuilder:1.0.0-vsc
SHELL ["powershell"]

# Download VC++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)
RUN Invoke-WebRequest http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/5/165255E7-1014-4D0A-B094-B6A430A6BFFC/vcredist_x64.exe  -OutFile "$env:TEMP\vc2010x64.exe" -UseBasicParsing  
RUN Start-Process "$env:TEMP\vc2010x64.exe" '/features + /q' -wait
RUN Remove-Item "$env:TEMP\vc2010x64.exe"

# Download VC++ 2012 Update 4 Redistributable Package (x64)
RUN Invoke-WebRequest http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/B/16B06F60-3B20-4FF2-B699-5E9B7962F9AE/VSU_4/vcredist_x64.exe  -OutFile "$env:TEMP\vc2012x64.exe" -UseBasicParsing  
RUN Start-Process "$env:TEMP\vc2012x64.exe" '/features + /q' -wait
RUN Remove-Item "$env:TEMP\vc2012x64.exe"

# Download VC++ 2013 Redistributable Package (x64)
RUN Invoke-WebRequest http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/6/2E61CFA4-993B-4DD4-91DA-3737CD5CD6E3/vcredist_x64.exe  -OutFile "$env:TEMP\vc2013x64.exe" -UseBasicParsing  
RUN Start-Process "$env:TEMP\vc2013x64.exe" '/features + /q' -wait
RUN Remove-Item "$env:TEMP\vc2013x64.exe"

# Note: Add MSBuild to path
RUN setx PATH '%PATH%;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin'  

# Download VC++ 2015 Build Tools
RUN Invoke-WebRequest 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126"&"fixForIE=.exe"&"__hstc=268264337.f43737e851d862336312053b3a368915.1511781465043.1511781465043.1511781465043.1"&"__hssc=268264337.1.1511781465043"&"__hsfp=1781426681' -OutFile "$env:TEMP\vc++2015bt.exe" -UseBasicParsing
RUN Start-Process "$env:TEMP\vc++2015bt.exe" '/features + /q' -wait
```

**Question**: I'm not sure what tools I'm missing on my container **so what is the above error and how can I resolve it**?

Comment: Are you able to built it without docker?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to build the project outside docker.